# How to change the symbol and color the Tab in AvalonEdit

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

How to change the symbol and color the **Tab** character

would like to change the character to the arrow character **→**[image]

and set the red color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For change color the Tab character

```
textEditor.TextArea.TextView.NonPrintableCharacterBrush = Brushes.Red;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source, you'll see that the character used to display a tab is hard coded:

https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/blob/106b31efe17a4992e1c02ee5c8650bc86591aeb7/ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit/Rendering/SingleCharacterElementGenerator.cs#L106

Comment: Thank you very much.
I figured out the first question.

The question remains open to me - Changing the color of the text.
Is not quite understood how to implement - DocumentColorizingTransformer.
It will not help with the second question - only if the Tab is at the beginning of the line

Comment: So you want to colorize the tab character, but only when it's the first character on the line?

Comment: Yes (0, 1, 2 ... ) StartWord. But in the first approximation, it is possible and in general all coincidences

Comment: I forgot about NonPrintableCharacterBrush, so I edited my answer. Though if you only want to colorize some tab characters and not others, you probably still need to use DocumentColorizingTransformer.

Comment: Thank you. 
Use DocumentColorizingTransformer need to understand the details